# Type conversion in C#, where is my error?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I "grew up" on Java and have recently made a full switch to C#. I am just teaching myself ATM, and just going back, redoing all my old programming assignments that were in Java using C# now. Here is a particular line of code where I am trying to use generics and instantiate the stack array.

```
stack = (T[])(new object[def_cap]);
```

which gives me this compiler error

```
Cannot convert type 'object[]' to 'T[]' (CS0030) 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'T[]' (CS0029)
```

I guess the cast operator works differently in C# than in Java, and was wondering if anyone could enlighten me. Thank you!

Comment: You can't cast `Object[]` to `T[]` in _Java_ either...

Comment: @K-ballo: The cast *will* compile but fail at runtime AFAIK.

Comment: In C# arrays are strictly typed. You cannot cast T[] to U[] unless T and U are the same type. Since you know the type, create an array of the required type directly as Femaref suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `stack = new T[def_cap];` instead. You already have the type and are able to use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an array to another type, you could do:

```
object[] objArr = new object[10];
T[] tArr = objArr.Cast<T>().ToArray();
```

Note that if the objects cannot be casted to type `T`, it will throw `InvalidCastException` on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

C# supports [array covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx) for reference-types only. So you must constraint generic parameter T to class:

```
    public static void Foo<T>() where T:class
    {
        T[] stack = (T[])(new object[def_cap]);
    }
```

But in your case, where you are casting object[] to T[], you will get InvalidCastException at runtime unless T is System.Object, because array covariance can cast X[] to Y[] only if Y is the same type as X or if X is class derived from Y (but not if Y is derived from X).